# Linker errors with opengl

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw, lnk2019

I am writing code in opengl using C++ in Visual Studio. I have done all the include directories correctly (including glfw include and glfw libraries in the properties), and lib directories correctly but I am getting this error

> 1.Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glViewport@16
>   referenced in function
>   _main timeinput2  C:\Users\user\source\repos\timeinput2\Source.obj    1
>   2.Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glOrtho@48 referenced
>   in function
>   _main timeinput2  C:\Users\user\source\repos\timeinput2\Source.obj    1
>   3.Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glMatrixMode@4
>   referenced in function
>   _main timeinput2  C:\Users\user\source\repos\timeinput2\Source.obj    1
>   4.Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glLoadIdentity@0
>   referenced in function
>   _main timeinput2  C:\Users\user\source\repos\timeinput2\Source.obj    1
>   5.Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced
>   in function
>   _main timeinput2  C:\Users\user\source\repos\timeinput2\Source.obj    1

Why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you add `opengl32` library (appart from the headers) to your project?

Comment: Did you set all the settings for  'All configurations' and not for a single (Debug/Release) mode?

Comment: These are linker errors. Nothing about include directories will fix them. Did it work when you ran a release build? If so, check the debug properties which are independent of the release properties.

Comment: ripi2 your suggestion worked i got the result.